# How to change the order of integration with normal standard distribution

Tags: integration, statistics, normal-distribution

I have a textbook that writes
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{\phi(s)}\int^{h}_{-\infty}{\phi(s+t)}dtds = \int^{h}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{\phi(s)\phi(t-s)dsdt}$$
where
$$\phi(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}$$
I suppose this is changing the order of integration, but have no idea how to get the right hand side.
Does anyone know how to derive it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make the change of variable $x=t, y=s+t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We substitute $s = - S \implies ds = - dS$. The limits of $s$ in integral change sign too.

$\displaystyle \phi (s) \ \phi(s+t) = \phi (-S) \ \phi(t-S) = \phi(S) \ \phi(t-S)$

Please note that,
$ \ \displaystyle \phi(-S)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(-S)^2/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-S^2/2} = \phi(S)$

So the integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^{h}_{-\infty}{\phi(s)} \ {\phi(s+t)} \ dt \ ds = -\int^{-\infty}_{\infty} \int^{h}_{-\infty} {\phi(S)} \ {\phi(t-S)} \ dt \ dS$

$\displaystyle  = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^{h}_{-\infty} {\phi(S)} \ {\phi(t-S)} \ dt \ dS = \int^{h}_{-\infty} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} {\phi(S)} \ {\phi(t-S)} \ dS \ dt$

For the last step, note that the order of integration can be simply swapped as the limits of both variables $t$ and $S$ are independent of each other.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I was trying substitution as well but did not work. I hadn't thought of s=-S. Thanks again.